# exclude file on specific path

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to exclude file on specific path (for example fe/dist), but it doesn work.

```
"files.exclude": {
  "**/dist": true,  // working, but exclude all dist folders (don't want)

  "fe/dist"         // not working
  "/fe/dist"        // not working
  "**/fe/dist"       // not working
  "./fe/dist"       // not working
  "${workspaceRoot}/fe/dist": true,         // not working
}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To exclude only a particular nested folder (for e.g. fe/dist), try

```
"files.exclude": {
     "**fe/dist": true
}
```